# Row Returned If Value Changed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following input

[image]

Whenever PRD column value changed then row should be returned. So My desired output is as follow:

[image]

My table structure 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHacZ.png)

Comment: I don't see any pattern for row ordering. Is there any rule/column we can apply for data sorting? Why the row with FILEID 1237 should be returned but no with FILEID 1263?

Answer (score 0):

Try using lag() function

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c9f7a02cc6a7f0e3015ccb717104958e)

```
select * from 
(
select *,lag(PRD,1,0) over(order by PRD,LOCID,FILEID) as pvalue
from tablename
)x where isnull(PRD,'1970-01-01')<>isnull(pvalue,'1970-01-01')
```

Comment: Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Comment: @irfan_db, modified the answer - you can check now

Comment: still same error 
select * from 
(
select *,lag(PRD,1,0) over(order by PRD,LOCID,FILEID) as pvalue
from test1
)x where isnull(PRD,'1970-01-01')<>isnull(pvalue,'1970-01-01')

Comment: @irfan_db, have u checked the demo? Is that working? it will be better if you provide your table structure

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `lag()`.  I think this is the correct logic:

```
select * 
from (select t.*,
             lag(prd) over (partition by locid order by fileid) as prev_prd
      from t
     ) t
where (prd <> prev_prd) or
      (prev_prd is null and prd is not null) or
      (prev_prd is not null and prd is null);
```

SQL Server does not have `NULL`-safe comparisons so the `NULL`s make the comparison logic a wee bit more complicated.

This assumes that `fileid` is the ordering for the rows.  If that is not the case, the `order by` needs to be the column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: returning only row 
2018-12-29 LOC00015866184     949 NULL